# The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration Or In Script Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Hey I'm trying to Define a mock database . I'm encountering an error while trying to equate var to Mock<'Repository'> The error is :

The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration Or In Script Code.

The Code that I have written is :

```
 public   class MockingDatabse
{
    //Mock a Payment Info
    var newPayment = new Mock<IPayment>();
}
```

I know that I can replace 'var' with 'Mock<"Repository">'. But I wanna know I'm not able to use 
'var'

Comment: Because the language doesn't let you.  The same way it doesn't let you declare a field `var x=0;`  It would work in a method...not at the class level

Comment: @forsvarir,  thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 public   class MockingDatabse
{
    //Mock a Payment Info
    Mock<IPayment> newPayment = new Mock<IPayment>();
}
```